# is there an UBUNTU distro for a motorola chip Mac?

Tags: mac, apple

i hate that a perfectly good hardware goes unused.
I have a few old motorolla chip laptops/desktops
that are "obsolete" 
Is there something I can use to reformat them to 
open source?

Answer (score 0):

Lubuntu offers [support for PowerPC](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ) on the LTS stream. [Download here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu).